# Facebook Test Account for Marketing Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, paypal, facebook-ads-api

I need to test process of creating ads by using facebook marketing api.
But I have a problem, when I try to create add by api I get oauth error. When I use power editor I get a message:

"Failed to create ad (ad_name)': 'You need to have a valid payment method associated with your ad account before you can create ads."

So, My question is Is there a way to create ad with out associated payment method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no 'ads sandbox' for creating ads for test purposes - all ads created via the API are live and need a valid account with valid billing info.

You should create the ads in status `PAUSED` and/or with very low bids if creating ads for testing your Ads API integration